# Java - Storing Several string inputs using a loop and input.nextline();

Tags: java, input

I'm trying to get a set of string statements (which can include spaces) into a string array. The number of statements will be decided by the input of the user.

So I thought of looping the `input.nextline();` function.
But I think as soon as enter is hit it is taken as `\n` to all the loops..
Is there any better way to do this?

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many Inputs??");    
    numOfInputs = input.nextInt();
    String[] dataStore = new String[numOfInputs];
    System.out.println("Input Strings");

    for(i=0;i<numOfInputs;i++){
        System.out.print("Input "+(i+1)+ " = ");

        dataStore[i] =  input.next();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many Inputs??");
    int numOfInputs = input.nextInt();
    String[] dataStore = new String[numOfInputs];
    System.out.println("Input Strings");

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfInputs; i++) {
        dataStore[i] = input.next();
        System.out.println("Input " + (i + 1) + " = " + dataStore[i]);

    }
}
```

Try this . I corrected the mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the bottom after the for loop, your code is working fine:

```
for(String str : dataStore) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```